# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing

I get an error at my site, It says this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /home/u199097780/public_html/wp-content/themes/xt-corporate-lite/templates/header.php on line 43. Here is my file  header.php:

```html
<?php
global $xt_corporate_lite_opt;
$site_logo = array();
if(isset($xt_corporate_lite_opt['xt_site_logo']) && $xt_corporate_lite_opt['xt_site_logo'] != '') {
    $site_logo = $xt_corporate_lite_opt['xt_site_logo'];
}
?>

<!-- Navigation -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-page">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only"><?php _e('Toggle navigation','xt-corporate-lite'); ?></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

                <?php
                if(isset($site_logo['url']) && $site_logo['url'] != ''){
                    $xt_logo = $site_logo['url'];
                    echo '<a class="page-scroll" href="'.esc_url(get_site_url()).'">';
                    echo '<img class="site_logo" src="'.esc_url($xt_logo).'">';
                    echo '</a>';
                    echo '<p class="site_description">'.get_bloginfo("description").'</p>';
                }else{
                    echo '<a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="'.esc_url(get_site_url()).'">';
                    bloginfo('site_title');
                    echo '</a>';
                    echo '<p class="site_description">'.get_bloginfo("description").'</p>';
                }
                ?>
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <?php
            if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary_navigation' ) ) {
                wp_nav_menu(['theme_location' => 'primary_navigation', 'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right', 'walker' => new xt_corporate_lite_navwalker(), 'depth' => '3']);
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
    <div class="page_header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-title">
                <h1><?php echo xt_corporate_lite_title(); ?></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I don't know much from PHP so i hope anyone can send the version that works for me

Comment: it's your PHP version.

Comment: @Fred-ii- what do you mean?

Comment: your PHP version doesn't support `wp_nav_menu(['theme_location'...`, you need to use `array()`.

Comment: can you send me a better version then? I'm new to PHP

Comment: a better version of what? lol WP or PHP?

Comment: @Fred-ii- of the file, you said i have to use array(), i don't know how. I also don't know what WP is lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- Why don't you send both? lol

Comment: @HareeshSivasubramanian I'm having breakfast right now; no time ;-)